# Line chart and bar chart in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Does anyone know how I go about putting a line chart for one set of values on top of a bar chart in GNU Plot? I've got the bar chart working just fine, but I've no idea how to add the line chart over the different columns.

I'm 100% lost! I can do it with excel quite easily but it doesn't look as good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With data file `Data.csv`:

```
9.0447e-01   7.6771e-01
3.6151e-01   9.9169e-01
7.0212e-01   4.4109e-02
9.1423e-01   7.7540e-05
```

and this script:

```
set boxwidth 0.6 relative
set style fill solid
plot "Data.csv" u 0:1 with boxes, "" u 0:2 with lines
```

you end up with this plot:

[image]

I hope this is what you were looking for. Of course, there still a lot one can do to improve the look of the plot.

Comment: Great! Thanks, I can sort the pretty red out myself :)